# Magento 2 add Item SR NO. in cart!

Tags: shopping-cart, magento2.3.0, cart-items, auto-increment

I have added new column of SR NO in cart table. But `<tbody>` tag generating dynamically. I want to add sr no for each row. but When I am trying it is not working and showing only 1 in each row.

Can you please let me know?

Here my code of default.phtml"

```
<?php   
 _item = $block->getItem();
    $helper1 = $this->helper('\Magento\Checkout\Helper\Cart');
    $totalItem = $helper1->getItemsCount();
    $product = $_item->getProduct();
    $i=1;
    $isVisibleProduct = $product->isVisibleInSiteVisibility();
    /** @var \Magento\Msrp\Helper\Data $helper */
    $helper = $this->helper('Magento\Msrp\Helper\Data');
    $canApplyMsrp = $helper->isShowBeforeOrderConfirm($product) && $helper->isMinimalPriceLessMsrp($product);


    ?>
    <?php
      // $i=1;

    //while($i<=$totalItem){

      ?>





    <tbody class="cart item">
        <tr class="item-info">
            <td class="col srn">

                <span><?php echo  $i . "<br>";

                      $i++;
                 ?></span> 

            </td>

            <td data-th="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Item')) ?>" class="col item">
                <?php if ($block->hasProductUrl()):?>
                    <a href="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getProductUrl() ?>"
                       title="<?= $block->escapeHtml($block->getProductName()) ?>"
                       tabindex="-1"
                       class="product-item-photo">
                <?php else:?>
                    <span class="product-item-photo">
                <?php endif;?>
                <?= $block->getImage($block->getProductForThumbnail(), 'cart_page_product_thumbnail')->toHtml() ?>
                <?php if ($block->hasProductUrl()):?>
                    </a>
                <?php else: ?>
                    </span>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <div class="product-item-details">
                    <strong class="product-item-name">
                        <?php if ($block->hasProductUrl()):?>
                            <a href="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getProductUrl() ?>"><?= $block->escapeHtml($block->getProductName()) ?></a>
                        <?php else: ?>
                            <?= $block->escapeHtml($block->getProductName()) ?>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </strong>
                    <?php if ($_options = $block->getOptionList()):?>
                        <dl class="item-options">
                            <?php foreach ($_options as $_option) : ?>
                                <?php $_formatedOptionValue = $block->getFormatedOptionValue($_option) ?>
                                <dt><?= $block->escapeHtml($_option['label']) ?></dt>
                                <dd>
                                    <?php if (isset($_formatedOptionValue['full_view'])): ?>
                                        <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_formatedOptionValue['full_view'] ?>
                                    <?php else: ?>
                                        <?= $block->escapeHtml($_formatedOptionValue['value'], ['span']) ?>
                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                </dd>
                            <?php endforeach; ?>
                        </dl>
                    <?php endif;?>
                    <?php if ($messages = $block->getMessages()): ?>
                        <?php foreach ($messages as $message): ?>
                            <div class="cart item message <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $message['type'] ?>"><div><?= $block->escapeHtml($message['text']) ?></div></div>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php $addInfoBlock = $block->getProductAdditionalInformationBlock(); ?>
                    <?php if ($addInfoBlock): ?>
                        <?= $addInfoBlock->setItem($_item)->toHtml() ?>
                    <?php endif;?>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="col size">
                 <span><?php if ($_options = $block->getOptionList()):?>
                        <dl class="item-options">
                            <?php foreach ($_options as $_option) : ?>
                           <span><?php if($block->escapeHtml($_option['label']) == 'Product Size') { ?></span>
                           <dd>
                            <?php echo $_option['value']; ?> 
                           </dd> 
                           <?php } ?>   
                            <?php endforeach; ?>
                        </dl>
                    <?php endif;?></span>
            </td> 
            <td class="col color">
                 <span><?php if ($_options = $block->getOptionList()):?>
                        <dl class="item-options">
                            <?php foreach ($_options as $_option) : ?>
                           <span><?php if($block->escapeHtml($_option['label']) == 'Color') { ?></span>
                           <dd>
                            <?php echo $_option['value']; ?> 
                           </dd> 
                           <?php } ?>   
                            <?php endforeach; ?>
                        </dl>
                    <?php endif;?></span>
            </td>   
            <?php if ($canApplyMsrp): ?>
                <td class="col msrp" data-th="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Price')) ?>">
                    <span class="pricing msrp">
                        <span class="msrp notice"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('See price before order confirmation.') ?></span>
                        <?php $helpLinkId = 'cart-msrp-help-' . $_item->getId(); ?>
                        <a href="#" class="action help map" id="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ ($helpLinkId) ?>" data-mage-init='{"addToCart":{"helpLinkId": "#<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $helpLinkId ?>","productName": "<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $product->getName() ?>","showAddToCart": false}}'>
                            <span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __("What's this?") ?></span>
                        </a>
                    </span>
                </td>
            <?php else: ?>
                <td class="col price" data-th="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Price')) ?>">
                    <?= $block->getUnitPriceHtml($_item) ?>
                </td>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <td class="col qty" data-th="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Qty')) ?>">
                <div class="field qty">
                    <label class="label" for="cart-<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_item->getId() ?>-qty">
                        <span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Qty') ?></span>
                    </label>
                    <div class="control qty">
                        <button type="button"   id="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_item->getId() ?>-dec"  class="decreaseQty"></button>
                       <input id="cart-<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_item->getId() ?>-qty"
                           name="cart[<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_item->getId() ?>][qty]"
                           data-cart-item-id="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_item->getSku() ?>"
                           value="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getQty() ?>"
                           type="number"
                           size="4"
                           title="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Qty')) ?>"
                           class="input-text qty"
                           data-validate="{required:true,'validate-greater-than-zero':true}"
                           data-role="cart-item-qty"/>                                                     

                          <button type="button"  id="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_item->getId() ?>-upt" class="increaseQty"></button>

                     <!--   <div class="qty_control">
                                <button type="button"   id="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_item->getId() ?>-dec"  class="decreaseQty"></button>
                                <button type="button"  id="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_item->getId() ?>-upt" class="increaseQty"></button>
                          </div> -->
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>

            <td class="col subtotal" data-th="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Subtotal')) ?>">
                <?php if ($canApplyMsrp): ?>
                    <span class="cart msrp subtotal">--</span>
                <?php else: ?>
                    <?= $block->getRowTotalHtml($_item) ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </td>
            <?php //} ?>
        </tr>
        <tr class="item-actions adde">
            <td colspan="4">
                <div class="actions-toolbar">
                    <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getActions($_item) ?>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

***Try below solution.***

**Magento_Checkout/templates/cart/form.phtml**

```
    <?php $i = 1;?>
    <?php foreach ($block->getItems() as $_item): ?>
          <?php $_item->setCartItemNo($i); ?>
          <?= $block->getItemHtml($_item) ?>
          <?php $i++; ?>
   <?php endforeach ?>
```

**Magento_Checkout/templates/cart/item/default.phtml**

```
$cartNo = $_item->getCartItemNo();

<td class="col no" data-th="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('No.')) ?>"><?= $cartNo ?></td>
```